# Passenger fails to generate webpage

Tags: apache, ubuntu, installation, passenger, bundler

I've really been struggling to get my webserver running on my computer.

I am running:
ruby 1.9.3
rvm 1.14.2 (stable)
gem 1.8.24

on a ubuntu server with apache and passenger.

I am able to get to my webpage but I keep getting this error message:

Ruby (Rack) application could not be started
A source file that the application requires, is missing.

```
It is possible that you didn't upload your application files correctly. Please check whether all your application files are uploaded.
A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.
```

Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.

Error message:
    cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
Exception class:
    LoadError
Application root:
    /srv/ftp/otto 
Backtrace:
    #   File    Line    Location
    0   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb  36  in `require'
    1   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb  36  in`require'
    2   /srv/ftp/otto/config/setup_load_paths.rb    15  in `'
    3   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb  36  in`require'
    4   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb  36  in `require'
    5   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb   301     in`prepare_app_process'
    6   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb    156     in `block in initialize_server'
    7   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb   572     in`report_app_init_status'
    8   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb    154     in `initialize_server'
    9   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb     204     in`start_synchronously'
    10  /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb     180     in `start'
    11  /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb    129     in`start'
    12  /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   253     in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
    13  /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb  132     in`lookup_or_add'
    14  /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   246     in `block in spawn_rack_application'
    15  /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb  82  in`block in synchronize'
    16      prelude>    10:in `synchronize'
    17  /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb  79  in`synchronize'
    18  /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   244     in `spawn_rack_application'
    19  /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   137     in`spawn_application'
    20  /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   275     in `handle_spawn_application'
    21  /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb     357     in`server_main_loop'
    22  /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb     206     in `start_synchronously'
    23  /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server    99  in`'

---

I have tried with:
Reinstalling rvm and ruby
installing bundler
... and some other stuff I didn't really understand!

Answer (score 0):

I had to specify my GEM_HOME which I did in my apache2.conf file...

I followed this guide:

https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/issues/123